# Can a class contain an instance of itself as a data container?

Tags: python, class, recursion

Can a python class contain an instance of itself as a data container may look like this?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.a = A(val)
        self.val = val

aa = A(2) 
#this will cause RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

My purpose is using this class as a data container contain a copy inside if it when it be inited to reduce the deepcopy action.
It may used as an "undo" chain give a chance to get the init val's value when it's necessary.

Is it possible for such an action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This won't work, for the reason already given:

1. Python sees `A(2)` and calls `A.__init__`.
2. `A.__init__` calls `A(val)`.
3. `A(val)` calls `A.__init__`.
4. GOTO 2

I assume you're doing this so that you have a log of what `val` has been; that is, if sometime later you decide that you want `val` to be `3` instead, you don't throw away the original value `2`. How about:

#### Code

```
class A( object ):
    @property
    def val( self ):
        return self.history[ -1 ]

    @val.setter
    def val( self, value ):
        self.history.append( value )

    def __init__( self, val ):
        self.history = [ ]
        self.val = val
```

#### Explanation

- `A( object )`: classes should now inherit from `object`. Just because, basically.
- `@property`: this tells python that every time we ask for A.val, it should call A.val() and return the result. This is a *decorator*; look up the `property` builtin function for more information.
- `@val.setter`: this is similar to the above, but tells Python that every time we try to assign to `A.val` it should call the following function instead. Instead of setting `A.val`, it appends the value to the history list.

Comment: If I copy and paste this exactly into ipython (with 2.7.5), then self.history=[] throws a NameError because self is not yet defined. Any advice what to do in that case? This looks like it will resolve my issues, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Yeah, good point, this is obviously wrong. `history` should be defined in the `__init__` method instead of at the class level.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, a class can contain an instance of itself, you just can't create it on initiation for the reasons described by others.

For example this class will do it,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value
    def setProperty(self,subvalue):
        self.innerInstance=A(subvalue)
```

You can then instantiate it and set its inner copy of itself like this:

```
>>>OuterInstance=A(123)
>>>OuterInstance.setProperty(456)
```

And verify it worked with:

```
>>>OuterInstance.innerInstance.value
456
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the class you have in self.a also has self.a, and so furher without an end. I'm not sure I get the purpose of what you are doing, but you might try something like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val, copy = True):
        if copy:
            self.a = A(val, False)
        self.val = val
```